# Jquery Load and send variables to url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the function "load" of Jquery for load page , in this url i send by "load" some values as this example :

```
jQuery("#load_data").show(1000).load("index.php?send_values="+datasend+"");
```

The value "datasend" get these values from function javascript as this :

```
    function getvalues()
    {
    var getdata="value 1";
    getdata +="value 2";
    getdata +="value 3";

var datasend=getdata;
    }
```

If insert alert inside funtion i get all values , for example :

```
        function getvalues()
        {
        var getdata="value 1";
        getdata +="value 2";
        getdata +="value 3";

    var datasend=getdata;

alert("Show"+datasend);
        }
```

But if i use load of Jquery , this no works :

```
       function getvalues()
        {
        var getdata="value 1";
        getdata +="value 2";
        getdata +="value 3";

    var datasend=getdata;

jQuery("#loader").load("index.php?send_values="+datasend);
        }
```

The other side in the page i want send/get values i have code in PHP , but when i do :

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['send_values'];?>
```

Only get the first data in this **case "value 1" and no all values** , but with javascript "alert" i get all values but **load** of jquery no send all values by URL for finally get all values

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: Are you sure you get "value 1"?

Comment: Um, the string would be "value 1value 2value 3" and you really should be encoding the querystring. What do you expect to be sent exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check again, you will see that the data that arrives at the server isn't `"value 1"`, but only `"value"`.

A correct URL can't contain spaces, so the [`load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) uses space as a separator between the URL and an optional selector to get a fragment from the loaded data. As there are spaces in the value in `datasend`, only the part up to the first space is included in the URL, the rest is interpreted as a selector.

You would use the `encodeURIComponent` method to encode the value so that it can be used in the URL:

```
jQuery("#loader").load("index.php?send_values=" + encodeURIComponent(datasend));
```

Alternatively you can use the data parameter of the `load` method to include the data:

```
jQuery("#loader").load("index.php", { send_values: datasend });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
var datasend=encodeURIComponent(getdata);
```